# Bert Embedding element #308

Tags: python, pytorch, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I've been getting some practice with Bert Embedding. Specifically, I'm using BERT-Base Uncased model with the PyTorch libraries

```py
    import torch
    from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertForMaskedLM
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

I noticed that for pretty much every word I've looked at the element #308 in the bert embedding 768-long vector is a negative outlier with the values below -2, perhaps half of the time below -4.

It is really weird. I tried to google something about 'bert embedding 308' but couldn't find anything.

I wonder if there is any explanation for this 'phenomenon'.

Here is my routine to extract the embeddings:

```py
def bert_embedding(text, bert_model, bert_tokenizer, layer_number = 0):
    marked_text = "[CLS] " + text + " [SEP]"    
    #the default is the last layer: 0-1 = -1
    layer_number -= 1
    tokenized_text = bert_tokenizer.tokenize(marked_text)
    indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)   
    segments_ids = [1] * len(tokenized_text)
    tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
    segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])

    with torch.no_grad():
        encoded_layers, _ = bert_model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)

    return encoded_layers[layer_number][0][:]
```

Comment: In neural networks for NLP, it is almost impossible to assign meaning to individual dimensions. Every time, you would re-train BERT, the weight would be totally different. I guess it is just a random artifact.

Comment: but isn't it strange that this particular element is almost always an outlier?

Comment: It is, indeed. :) But I still believe it only a strange random artifact.

Comment: Did you consider retraining BERT model from scratch. (without using a pre-trained model) ?